# How to see the feature importance of a prediction in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a simple RF classifier model trained with a sample dataset and it works fine.

So, I use some test data to predict the target class and let's say it find the target class as `1` or `0` (for simplicity, think of it as a binary classification)

So let's say we need to see the impact of the **testing** features for the predicted value (`0` or `1`). Look at below example:

```
input features - [a,b,c]
predicted value - 1

input features - [a,d,c]
predicted value - 10
```

So let's take the first scenario where input (testing features) features are `a`, `b` and `c` which will produce `1`

So now I want to check out of there features (`a`, `b`, `c`), what is/are the features that mostly impacted to predict the value `1`

How can I do this?

PS: i know how to check feature importance for a training dataset, but in this case, it is not a training dataset, it is the testing dataset and target class is only obtain after the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

One package I used for explaining the predictions of a RF classifier is the Treeinterpreter. It calculates the contribution of individual features on individual predictions: "Package for interpreting scikit-learn’s decision tree and random forest predictions. Allows decomposing each prediction into bias and feature contribution components..." https://pypi.org/project/treeinterpreter/

This blog [here](http://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests) explain how it works and this [here](http://blog.datadive.net/random-forest-interpretation-with-scikit-learn/) shows examples how to use it. But basically once you have your RF model:

```
from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti
prediction, bias, contributions = ti.predict(model, data)
```

Model is the RF model and data is the test data (the dataset for which you generate predictions)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this, can you provide some example/s on this? how to do this?

Comment: Thank you, and I guess `model` is the my RF model and what is `data` parameter?

Comment: This blog [here] (http://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/) explain how it work and this [here] (http://blog.datadive.net/random-forest-interpretation-with-scikit-learn/) shows examples how to use it. But basically once you have your model:
`from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti`
..
`prediction, bias, contributions = ti.predict(model, data)`

Model is your RF model and data is your test data (the dataset for which you generate predictions)

Comment: Thank you. Can you update your answer with the content you put in above comment? Because it might help someone in future. (probably he/she will miss the comments)

Comment: Hi @Mel, I got a problem. When I try to get the feature importance, there is only one feature (out of 17 features) that has a value all others are 0.0000. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, not sure, Do you mean all the contributions are 0 except for one feature? I just posted in your other question about the sorting, how I was processing the results (the sorting by contribution).

Comment: Normally this should be true: prediction=bias+feature1contribution+…+featurencontribution.

Comment: Yes, all the contributions are 0 except for one feature. I don't know why it happens. But when I do a normal feature importance (I am using Naive Bayesian Gaussian model) it also doesn't show more than 2-4 features being the most important features. Am I using the wrong machine learning model?

Comment: I thought you are using a Random forest classifier. If you check the package description it says: "It works on scikit-learn’s

DecisionTreeRegressor
DecisionTreeClassifier
ExtraTreeRegressor
ExtraTreeClassifier
RandomForestRegressor
RandomForestClassifier
ExtraTreesRegressor
ExtraTreesClassifier"

Comment: I am using it. I have trained a model with the dataset I have with `Random forest classifier` and even tried 'naive bayes` as well. both gives the same result (only one feature making the importance for predicting the target variable)

Comment: And this is happening for all the entries (all rows in your test dataset), for all of them you have only one feature contributing? Is this formula true in your case prediction=bias+feature1contribution+…+featurencontribution?

Comment: for your question `And this is happening for all the entries (all rows in your test dataset), for all of them you have only one feature contributing?` the answer is `yes` not just one, there are 2-3 features but only one is significantly being important.

Comment: Is your dataset public or can you share it? I could try to play a bit with it.